# CSS - Left and Right alignment on the same line

Tags: html, css

Below is some sample code, which has all the links right-justified.  I would like to change the CSS so the "Left" link is left-justified, the others are right-justified, but they are all on the same line.  How do I do that?

Thanks in advance,

John

The HTML:

```
<div class="mainlinks">
    <a href="left.php" class="links">Left</a>
    <a href="right1.php" class="links">Right1</a>
    <a href="right2.php" class="links">Right2</a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.mainlinks
    {
    text-align:right;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }

 a.links:link {
    color: #FF0000; text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-top:300px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:2px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Float the left  to the left

```
.left {float:left;}

    <div class="mainlinks">
        <a href="left.php" class="links left">Left</a>
        <a href="right1.php" class="links">Right1</a>
        <a href="right2.php" class="links">Right2</a>
    </div>
```

**But** you need to remove the margin-top:300px from  `a.links:link` otherwise the left will be 300px below the right.

Comment: Thanks, Emily.  Your simple solution worked perfectly.  Also, thanks for helping me yesterday by suggesting Firebug for the other question I asked.

Answer (score 15):

It's an old post, but it's well ranked on google so it's still relevant.

I used another way to align both right and left on the same line, without using any ugly float. It makes use of a table-like display :

HTML :

```
    <footer>
      <nav>links (to the left)</nav>
      <p>copyright (to the right)</p>
    </footer>
```

CSS :

```
    footer
    {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }
    footer nav
    {
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: left;
    }
    footer p
    {
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: right;
    }
```

I find it much cleaner this way.

Hope this helps someone !

Comment: Wow this is one amazing solution! What I love about this is that it's very clean and I don't have to use `float` (which require a clear:both after it).

Comment: That's great!  This should be the new accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Put each in a seperate div. Float one left, one right. Set the widths.

```
<div class="mainlinks">
    <div class="left">    
        <a href="left.php" class="links">Left</a>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <a href="right1.php" class="links">Right1</a>
        <a href="right2.php" class="links">Right2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mainlinks .left {
    float:left;
    width: 49%;
}

.mainlinks .right {
    float:right;
    width: 49%;
}
```

Comment: This assumes that there is no margin/border on the divs. The percentages would be better as px for the lengths of the divs.

Comment: I have a "<div class="line"></div>" directly beneath my links, but with your set-up above, my links are now below the line.  Moreover, the link I would like to be at the left side of the screen is now in the center.  The right-links are in place as usual.

Comment: You'll need to clear the floats. Stick a div with a  style of clear:both underneat the mainlinks div.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.mainlinks
    {
    text-align:right;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }

 a.links:link {
    color: #FF0000; text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-top:300px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:2px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    }

.right { float: right }
.left { float: left }

</style>
<div class="mainlinks">
    <a href="left.php" class="links left">Left</a>
    <a href="right1.php" class="links right">Right1</a>
    <a href="right2.php" class="links right">Right2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this setup, and it drastically altered the appearance of my page.  Maybe I'll keep tinkering.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put it to separate blocks (div) or override via more specific CSS applying to the link as proposed by @skurpur

i believe you must add display:block to the link to position it - e.g. only block elements can be positioned.

Comment: I tried that, and the left link was a line above the right link.  I want them on the same line.

Comment: well, you need to study CSS more to understand the box model. you need to float one element to the left and the other one to the right (or both to the left setting width to 50% - assuming no other padding/margin and borders are set).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex;` on container with `justify-content: space-between;` and `align-items: baseline;`. There is good sass mixin for flex supporting old and new syntax: https://github.com/mastastealth/sass-flex-mixin